# How to convert an array to an object?

Tags: javascript

I have some data that comes like an array, i will show you it looks

```
Vm.table=[{
 Name:"amina";
},
{
 Prenom:"adfe";
},
 {
  Region:"rabat";
 }];
```

To an object like

```
Vm.obj={
    Name:"amina",
    Prenom:"adfe",
    Region:"rabat"
  };
```

I need to set a code that may convert the table to this object, i put a lot of functions but is not working to me if someone can help.

Comment: "i put a lot of functions" - but you are showing no attempt.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.assign()` and `spread` operator

```js
const table=[{Name:"amina"},{Prenom:"adfe"},{Region:"rabat"}];
 
 const result = Object.assign({}, ...table);
 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce`

```
Vm.obj = Vm.table.reduce((obj, col) => {
    Object.keys(col).forEach(k => obj[k] = col[k])
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Of course, if you have repeating keys, this will take the last key/val pair available.

Comment: it works i didn't use reduce before thanks for information and help

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.prototype.reduce` and I am assuning objects have only single key, value pair.

```js
let array =[{
 Name:"amina"
},
{
 Prenom:"adfe"
},
 {
  Region:"rabat"
 }];
 
 let obj = array.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    const key = Object.keys(curr)[0];
    prev[key] = curr[key];
    return prev;
 }, {});
 
 console.log(obj);
```

Comment: yeah i see the interest to use reduce its working thanks